# How to specify different padding methods while generating signature using openssl?

Tags: .net, openssl, cryptography, rsa, sha256

Our server team is generating the signature for the given checksum by using the code below (.net code).

```
Convert.ToBase64String(rsap.SignHash(SHA256.HashData(Convert.FromHexString(strHash)), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));
```

They are using RSA signature padding.

The checksum I created using sha256 as below

```
sha256sum v.tgz | awk '{printf $1}' > chksum
```

But from our client side, using shell, even though we are using the same private certificate, we are getting different signature for same checksum.

We are using below command to generate the signature on shell.

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ipdvr-private-key.pem chksum | openssl base64 -A
```

Both signatures generated (on server side using .net an on client side using shell) are completely different.

I was thinking it is because we haven't specified RSA signature padding while generating the signature on shell.

Can any one please let me know if this is indeed the reason or what options I need to specify to openssl command on shell in order to generate the same signature as on server side.

Comment: RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1 = PKCS #1 v1.5 and this signature type is non-deterministic: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66521/744 So if you generate the same signature twice on your server it will be different. Signatures are not compared at byte level, instead verify the signature to test if it is valid or not.

Comment: @Robert - PKCS#1 v1.5 in the context of signing (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5) is deterministic. Your link refers to PKCS#1 v1.5 in the context of encrypting (RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5), which is non-deterministic.

Comment: @Topaco But isn't RSA signing in this context not an encryption of the hash plus padding? Specifying two different padding types using the same name doesn't make any sense (which does not mean it is impossible that someone specified it this way).

Comment: @Robert - Both padding variants actually have different names (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 for signing, RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 for encrypting). The reason that they are sometimes referred to as PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is that they were first described in [RFC2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313) (PKCS#1: v1.5, March 1998). The current version is PKCS#1 v2.2, Nov. 2016 ([RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017)). Here, RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is described in [section 8.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2).